# jquery find next element with class name

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Morgage application completed (if yes please enter date)</label>
    <span id="RblMorgAppComp" class="rblLocal checkonchange">
    <input id="RblMorgAppComp" type="radio" name="RblMorgAppComp" value="Yes">
    <label for="RblMorgAppComp">Yes</label>
    <input id="RblMorgAppComp" type="radio" name="RblMorgAppComp" value="No">
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RblMorgAppComp_1">No</label></span>
    <div class="input-group date datepick">
        <input name="TxtMorgAppCompDate" type="text" id="TxtMorgAppCompDate" class="form-control rddt">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following jquery.

```
        $('.checkonchange input').change(function () {
            var rdlVal = $(this).val();
            if (rdlVal == 'Yes') {
                //$(this).parent().parent().next('input').find('.rddt').css('border', 'solid 1px #000');
                $(this).nextAll('.rddt').val('ddddd');
                //$('.rddt').focus();
                //alert($(this).next('.rddt').val());
                //alert($(this).nextAll('.rddt').text());
                //$(this).next('.rddt').css('border', 'solid 1px #000');
                //$(this).closest("input['type=text']").css('border', 'solid 1px #000');
            }
        });
```

I'm trying to change the focus to the text box if the user selects yes. As you can see I have tried numerous things, but I can't get it to work.

I'm sure it must be something simple. I can't just find the class name because I have many of these radio buttons and text boxes on the 1 page.

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/0cdbb5fr/)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set value for all inputs with class `.rddt` which located in class `.form-group` (focus will be on last input)

```
$(this).closest('.form-group').find('.rddt').val('YES').focus();
```

Also you can use ID

```
$('#TxtMorgAppCompDate').val('YES').focus();
```

[`Example`](http://jsbin.com/hazumu/1/edit?html,js,output)